# Как сменить путь к файлам translation.json в i18next?

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

Проблема следующая - есть React приложение собранное create-react-app. Я хочу разместить его на GitHub Pages, но тогда к адресной строке добавляется название проекта myname.github.io/**project**.
Эта проблема решается добавлением строчки homepage в package.json

```js
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "/project",
  ...
```

Но после добавления библиотека i18next не видит файлов локализации по адресу /public/locales/en/translation.json
Пробовал так /public/project/locales/en/translation.json - не работает.
Буду благодарен за советы.

Comment: настройте i18next с использованием нового пути. вы можете это сделать, вызывая `i18next.init()` с настройками, которые указывают новый путь к файлам локализации. Но лучше разобраться, почпму не видит пусть

Comment: `i18next.init({
lng: 'en',
resources: {
en: {
translation: require('/public/project/locales/en/translation.json')
}
}
});



i18next.init({
lng: 'en',
resources: {
en: {
translation: require('/public/project/locales/en/translation.json')
}
}
});`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй  так:  '/project/locales/en/translation.json'